# Java class properties being overwritten by null json properties

Tags: java, json

I have the following code:

```
public class Member {

    public int age;
    public String name;
    public String type = "poolMember";

    public Member() {
        type = "poolMember";
    }
}

void newMember() {
    String newMembers = 
           "[{\"age\":\"43\",\"name\":\"Jon\"},
            {\"age\":\"25\",\"name\":\"Tom\",\"type\":\"clubMember\"}]";
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Member>>() {
    }.getType();
    ArrayList<Member> members = gson.fromJson(newMembers, listType);


}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
  newMember();
  }
```

I'd like the Member.type to equal "poolMember" if it is not defined in the json string but it is currently null.

I understand this can be achieved with [instance creator](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/InstanceCreator.html) but I need help to implement this.

EDIT

added to newMember():

```
 System.out.println(members.get(0).type);
 result = null
```

Comment: Your code works for me... Where do you see it being `null`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis members[0].Type = null ie the array that us populated by gson.fromJson Jons type = null

Comment: It's an `ArrayList`. Access it as `members.get(0).type`. It returns `poolMember` for me.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I tested as you suggested, strange the result is definitely null for me as per question edit

Comment: You can for example make your attributes private and implement Getters/Setters with a special case for `type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following

```
public class Test {
    static public class Member {

        public int age;
        public String name;
        public String type = "poolMember";

        public Member() {
            type = "poolMember";
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "[age = " + age + ", name = " + name + ", type = " + type
                    + "]";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String newMembers = "[{\"age\":\"43\",\"name\":\"Jon\"},{\"age\":\"25\",\"name\":\"Tom\",\"type\":\"clubMember\"}]";
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Member>>() {
        }.getType();
        ArrayList<Member> members = gson.fromJson(newMembers, listType);

        System.out.println(members);

    }
}
```

prints

```
[[age = 43, name = Jon, type = poolMember], [age = 25, name = Tom, type = clubMember]]
```

Are you sure you are printing the right `members`?

Comment: Setting Member to a static class got it working, I'm not sure why as I'm new to java I'm off to read about it now. Thanks for the help

Comment: @andrew You should probably declare your `Member` class in its own `.java` file. That fact that there was no `static` made the class an `inner` class. Gson probably does some weird reflection thing when working with inner classes.